# iOS - BarButtonItem Corner spacing in UINavigatioItem

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I am creating RightBarButtonItem in UINavigationItem, Programmatically.
Using this simple code

```
UIButton *backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
[backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"concate_back_icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
```

Which Produces correct results, but there is an issue, There is little space between the botton and screen corner, which I don't want.

[image: 1st image]

For that purpose I add spacing in button image, using edge insets

```
[backButton setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -10, 0,10)];
```

Which get me good visual results but the clickable area remained the same and So user misses the click most of the times.

[image: Image 2]

And now I am stuck here.
Kindly let me know if there is another way to changing the corner space of bar button item. 
I have to stick with navigationItem.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to set the right edge insets to the barbutton based on your expectation. It works for me. Please let me know if you face issues. Thanks.

```
let rightBarButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
rightBarButton.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "Settings"), for: .normal)
rightBarButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
rightBarButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(someAction), for: .touchUpInside)
rightBarButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: -30.0) // Right edge insets
let rightBar = UIBarButtonItem(customView: rightBarButton)
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem  = rightBar
```

Comment: It has same results as SetImageEdgeInsets. The Image gets an offset but not the button. So if I click the area where there image but not button, the button selector doesn't get called.
I hope you can understand the issue.